# How do I check SEO Friendly CMS?

Tags: google-search, cms, local-seo, seo-audit

How do I measure whether a website CMS is SEO friendly or not? Are there any manual methods or online tools to check?

Because I have been seen for about one year that some of my competitor's websites have not enough content and also they don't do SEO properly. But when I search on Google with Business Keywords then their result comes first. I think that my site's CMS is not good and as a result, I am behind them. So it needs to know for me that how can I check my website CMS that is the CMS SEO friendly or not?

Comment: You can't except crawling forums and checking personal opinions.